# how to remove picture from data using api in react

Tags: json, reactjs, api

so i am trying to learn api and doing this cool project. so what i have is that i got photos data from this api website:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

so basically i have a buttom that will add thumbnail data from api based on the albumId in the posts section and when i press on the image it will send the url of the image to a function which will load it on top.

so what i want is to be able to remove the picture up top to have like this red x next to it and when i press it it will be deleted from the upper section and also from the posts section.

my code so far:

```
const DataFetching = () =>{

    const [photo,setPhoto] = useState([])
    const[albumId,setAlbumId] = useState(1)
    const[albumIdFromButtonClick,setAlbumAIdFromButtonClick] = useState(1)

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?albumId=${albumIdFromButtonClick}`)
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res)
            setPhoto(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    },[albumIdFromButtonClick])

    const handleClick = () => {
        setAlbumAIdFromButtonClick(albumId)
    }

    const [Url,setUrl] = useState()

    const showPicture = (url) => {
        setUrl(url)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div><img src={Url}></img></div>
            <div>Posts</div>
            <p>enter album Id to see the magic</p><input type="text" value={albumId} onChange={e => setAlbumId(e.target.value)}></input>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Fetch Album</button>
            <div className="container">
            <div>{photo.map(p => 
                <div key={p.id}>
                    <img src={p.thumbnailUrl} thumbnailUrl={p.thumbnailUrl} onClick={() => showPicture(p.url)}></img>
                        <div>{p.title}</div>
                </div>
            )}</div>
            </div>
            {/* {
                photos.map(photo => <div key={photo.id}>{photo.title}</div>)
            } */}
        </div>
    )
}



export default DataFetching;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I expect you have an button to delete the post image.

When you are clicking in the button you are calling deleteImageFromAlbum() method for example.
So the code will be :

```
const deleteImageFromAlbum = photoID => {
  setUrl('')
  setPhoto(photos.filter(photo => photo.id !== photoID));
}
```

the `filter` method update the array and takes all photos which the id is not equal to the targeted photos.

Comment: `photos.filter` will do nothing. `filter` does not update array, it creates new array.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to put filter inside setPhotos, I will update this

Answer (score 0):

You create a function to handle delete action. It returns new `photo` with removed record that matches `id`

```
const handleDelete = id => {
    setUrl(null);
    setPhoto(prevState => prevState.filter(x => x.id !== id));
  };
```

and you then you add this button somewhere inside rendered list

```
<div onClick={() => handleDelete(p.id)}>delete</div>
```

In case you want just delete open prevew:

```
const hanldeDeletePreview = url => {
 setUrl(null);
 setPhoto(prevState => prevState.filter(x => x.url !== url));
};
```

and add button somewhere like this

```
<div>
 <img src={Url} />
 <div onClick={() => hanldeDeletePreview(Url)}>delete</div>
</div>
```

It filters you list by `url` so it if you have list with matching urls then it will delete all of them. If you want to delete it based on `id` then you should redo your url preview logic to use `id` instead.

Here is the rewrite that uses `id` to show preview

```
  const [previewId, setPreviewId] = useState(null);

  const showPicture = id => {
    setPreviewId(id);
  };

  const handleDelete = id => {
    setPhoto(prevState => prevState.filter(x => x.id !== id));
  };

  const hanldeDeletePreview = id => {
    setPreviewId(null);
    handleDelete(id);
  };

  const previewHelper = () => {
    const selected = photo.find(x => x.id === previewId);
    return selected ? (
      <>
        <img src={selected.url} />
        <div onClick={() => hanldeDeletePreview(previewId)}>delete preview</div>
      </>
    ) : null;
  };
```

```
return (
    <div>
      <div>{previewHelper()}</div>
      <div>Posts</div>
...

<img
  src={p.thumbnailUrl}
  thumbnailUrl={p.thumbnailUrl}
  onClick={() => showPicture(p.id)}
/>
```